# Memory allocation using pointer VS without using pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Is there any difference in terms of memory usage between the following two codes in C++?

```
int *val = new int(5);
```

and

```
int val = 5;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your first example requires at least `sizeof(int*)` (in automatic storage) + `sizeof(int)` (in dynamic storage). There may also be overhead from the memory management.

Your second example only requires `sizeof(int)` which may end up being omitted entirely (by optimization) depending on how its used.

Comment: @SergeyA would you care to explain that statement for a casual c++ programmer? I always thought `B b()` was stack and `B *b = new B()` was heap... did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

> *"Is there any difference in terms of memory usage between the following two codes in C++?"*

Of course, your 1st example leaks memory unless you're not calling `delete val;` after you don't need it anymore.

You might want to read about the [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom, regarding your 2nd sample (though just dealing with simple `int` values all that turns out to be trivial).

Note c++ `new` isn't handled the same way as in [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) language, there's no garbage collector.